# Best way to calculate UTC time

Tags: c#, datetime

Which is the best way to calculate the UTC date time:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now)
```

or

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

Which method consider daylight affects too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will do the same thing, the second would most likely be a tiny bit faster. It will take into account daylight savings if it's enabled on the machine.

[DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Gets a DateTime object that is set to the **current date and time on this computer**, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: Depending on the windows version and configuration, it is also entirely possible that the hardware / BIOS system clock is in UTC (which is normal for most OS except windows). Even more reason to use the `UtcNow` approach.